# Passing a variable from javascript to Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I want to send a variable I got from a javascript function to my Django view. The function is as below:

```
<script>
      function googleSignin() {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
            console.log(token)
            console.log(user)
            var uid = user.uid;
            return uid;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
          
            console.log(error.code)
            console.log(error.message)
        });
      }
</script>
```

I used a onclick tag to call this function and the values properly show up in the console. I just need to send the value returned to my views somehow. I've tried using ajax to call on the view but I can't figure out how to make it work. The ajax code is below:

```
 $.ajax({
      // points to the url where your data will be posted
      url: /gsignin/,
      // post for security reason
      type: "POST",
      // data that you will like to return 
      data: {uid : uid},
      // what to do when the call is success 
      success:function(response){
        console.log(sid);
      },
      // what to do when the call is complete ( you can right your clean from code here)
      complete:function(){
        window.location.href = "/gsignin/"
      },
      // what to do when there is an error
      error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){}
  });
```

I'm really new to this stuff but I can't find any proper documentation on implementing this ajax. Also it is not necessary to use the ajax jquery at all, I just need to pass the returned variable from the function.

Comment: You need `uid` ?

Comment: Yes uid is the key from which I call stuff from my firebase real time database and storage, I just need to pass it to the backend easily so that I can create my session.

Comment: after this line `var uid = user.uid;` call function and pass uid value as parameter  i.e : `somefunction(uid)` then inside your function add that ajax code .